# Add custom google map in sencha architect

Tags: google-maps, sencha-architect

Please I would like to add code to customise the google map added to my application in Sencha Architect. I have added the map but i do not know what code to use to make the map show the current location and surrounding bustops. I also do not know where to place the code in Sencha Architect. Should i place it in the mapoption config or the geo config or somewhere else. Please help i am new to Sencha Architect

Answer (score 0):

Location must be in geo config, everything else in mapoption.